# How to design a generic filter like ecommerce website have using ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rxjs, lodash

i am planning to build a generic filter like [Gbif](https://www.gbif.org/occurrence/search?q=) Have.
My question is how to approach this problem.
I like to use ReactJs for this project.
What other technology i need to look into along with React and redux in order to design such a generic filter.

I try to design this filter using React and redux only.

In my approach, i try to maintain the query parameter inside the state variable of the get_data method, in which i am fetching the data from the server. As somebody click on any filter button, then i pass custom event from that filter component along with query parameter and handle this event in get_data method. In get_data method again i am saving this value in get_data state parameter and again getting the new filtered data.

Now the Problem with above approach is that as the number of parameter increases it become very difficult to maintain.

my get_data constructor look like this.

```
 constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        params:{
          max:10,
          offset:0,
          taxon:[],
          sGroup:[],
          classification:undefined,
          userGroupList:[],
          isFlagged:undefined,
          speciesName:undefined,
          isMediaFilter:undefined,
          sort:"lastRevised",
          webaddress:""

        },
        title:[],
        groupName:[],
        userGroupName:[],
        view:1
      }


      this.props.fetchObservations(this.state.params)
      this.loadMore=this.loadMore.bind(this);
    };
```

The way i am getting data from filter component is something like this.

this is my  handleInput method which fire onSelect method from  one of the filter.

```
handleInput(value,groupName){
    this.setState({
      active:true
    })
    this.props.ClearObservationPage();
    var event = new CustomEvent("sGroup-filter",{ "detail":{
        sGroup:value,
        groupName:groupName
    }
  });
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
  };
```

the way i am handling this event in my get_data component is look something like this.

```
sGroupFilterEventListner(e){
        const params=this.state.params;
        if(!params.sGroup){
          params.sGroup=[];
        }
        console.log("params.sGroup",params.taxon)
        params.sGroup.push(e.detail.sGroup)
        params.sGroup=_.uniqBy(params.sGroup)
        const groupName=this.state.groupName;
        var titleobject={};
        titleobject.sGroup=e.detail.sGroup;
        titleobject.groupName=e.detail.groupName;
        groupName.push(titleobject);
        let newgroupname=_.uniqBy(groupName,"sGroup")

        params.classification=params.classification;
        let isFlagged=params.isFlagged;
        let speciesName=params.speciesName;
        let MediaFilter=params.isMediaFilter;

        let taxonparams=params.taxon;
        taxonparams= taxonparams.join(",");
        let sGroupParams=params.sGroup;
            sGroupParams=sGroupParams.join(",");
        let userGroupParams=params.userGroupList;
         userGroupParams=userGroupParams.join(",");

        let newparams={
                  max:10,
                  sGroup:sGroupParams,
                  classification:params.classification,
                  offset:0,
                  taxon:taxonparams,
                  userGroupList:userGroupParams,
                  isFlagged:isFlagged,
                  speciesName:speciesName,
                  isMediaFilter:MediaFilter,
                  sort:params.sort

                }

        this.props.fetchObservations(newparams);
        this.setState({
                params:{
                  max:10,
                  sGroup:params.sGroup,
                  classification:params.classification,
                  offset:0,
                  taxon:params.taxon,
                  userGroupList:params.userGroupList,
                  isFlagged:isFlagged,
                  speciesName:speciesName,
                  isMediaFilter:MediaFilter,
                  sort:params.sort

                },
              groupName:newgroupname
        })
      }
```

I registered and unRegistered the sGroupFilterEventListner in my componentDidMount and componentunmount method.

Presently i am also not considering the case where if somebody type in url bar, the filter panel change automatically.

Please consider all the above scenario and suggest me a generic way to do the same. thanks.

My Current Filter Panle look like this
[image]

Comment: You really shouldn't need custom event listeners in document scope when you're using React (and/or Redux)...

Comment: Custom filters can also come from the backend. So, when you go into a product category and you want to search, you can have the backend send you down json containing the filter options. These will then be sent back to the server which will filter the data. There is very little the front really has to do!

Comment: Are you using RxJS somewhere that isn't shown?

Comment: @paulpdaniels no i am not using RxJS. Is there need to use RxJS.
Even if there is no need of RxJS, is using RxJS make task easy?

Comment: No. But you tagged it, so you may want to remove that tag.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick example (React only, no Redux) I whipped up with a dynamic number of filters (defined in the `filters` array, but naturally you can acquire that from wherever).

```js
const filters = [
  { id: "name", title: "Name", type: "string" },
  {
    id: "color",
    title: "Color",
    type: "choice",
    choices: ["blue", "orange"],
  },
  {
    id: "height",
    title: "Height",
    type: "choice",
    choices: ["tiny", "small", "big", "huge"],
  },
  {
    id: "width",
    title: "Width",
    type: "choice",
    choices: ["tiny", "small", "big", "huge"],
  },
];

const filterComponents = {
  string: ({ filter, onChange, value }) => (
    <input
      value={value || ""}
      onInput={e => onChange(filter.id, e.target.value)}
    />
  ),
  choice: ({ filter, onChange, value }) => (
    <select
      value={value || ""}
      onInput={e => onChange(filter.id, e.target.value)}
      size={1 + filter.choices.length}
    >
      <option value="">(none)</option>
      {filter.choices.map(c => (
        <option value={c} key={c}>
          {c}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  ),
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { filters: {} };
    this.onChangeFilter = this.onChangeFilter.bind(this);
  }
  onChangeFilter(filterId, value) {
    const newFilterState = Object.assign({}, this.state.filters, {
      [filterId]: value || undefined,
    });
    this.setState({ filters: newFilterState });
  }
  renderFilter(f) {
    const Component = filterComponents[f.type];
    return (
      <div key={f.id}>
        <b>{f.title}</b>
        <Component
          filter={f}
          value={this.state.filters[f.id]}
          onChange={this.onChangeFilter}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{filters.map(f => this.renderFilter(f))}</td>
            <td>Filters: {JSON.stringify(this.state.filters)}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("main"));
```

```css
body {
  font: 12pt sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main/>
```

(originally on https://codepen.io/akx/pen/JyemQQ?editors=0010)

Hope this helps you along.

Comment: Honestly, I've not tried this solution but if it works then this is actually stunning because I was implementing the similar kind of solution the other day and my code length was 5 times more than this.